# how to get the immediate previous node and next node of the Current selected TreeNode in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, treeview

I have created TreeView in asp.net page.When user select the any node then i want to get the immediate previous TreeNode and immediate next TreeNode of the current selected TreeNode.There is a method in C# windows form application.But it is not available in web controls TreeView.

for example :
[image]

Suppose,

1. user selecting "Sales Order Detail" then i want to get previous Node ->"Product Line   Sales" and next Node ->"Territory Sales Drilldown"

   2.User selecting "SampleReports" then i want to get the Previous Node->"Employees" and next Node ->"Company Sales".

Answer (score -1):

this shold get you the index of the selected node and then you can try to specify the neighbors nodes based on the index to be selected.  I hope it helps.

```
  TreeNode obj = new TreeNode();
  obj = treeView1.SelectedNode;
  index = treeView1.Nodes.IndexOf(obj);
  TreeNode oTreeNode = treeView1.GetNodeFromIndex((index-1).ToString());
  oTreeNode.select();
  TreeNode oTreeNode2 = treeView1.GetNodeFromIndex((index+1).ToString());
  oTreeNode2.select();
```

Comment: There is no such method GetNodeFromIndex() in TreeView.How do i call it?

Comment: I am using VS-2010.It is not listed the method you specified above.

Comment: This only apply to Asp.Net we apps, not WinForm.